# Naturally way to deduce 'the form' of adjoint functors from the naturality diagrams

Tags: category-theory

I'm really stuck calculating left and right adjoints. I'm trying to find a left adjoint and a right adjoint to the forgetful functor $U: Vect_{\mathbb{k}} \rightarrow Set$. I know that the functor $F: Set \rightarrow Vect_{\mathbb{k}}$ that sends a set to the free vector space on it is a left adjoint of $U$, and when I put it in the diagrams

[image]

it works, but I can't see how this naturality could lead me to the functor F. Is there a natural way to obtain this left adjoint seeing the needed properties? What about the right adjoint?

Comment: If you're asking how to find left adjoints: It's not trivial to find adjoints but usually those are  "natural constructions" (indeed, they satisfy naturality conditions). For example, if you want to construct left adjoints of forgetful functors, then these should be "free" constructions, i.e. you should somehow get the universal object that has the additional structure we've forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ has no right adjoint since $U$ does not preserve colimits. For example, $U$ does not preserve the initial object: $U(0)$ is not the empty set.

Comment: Is the case $U: Group \rightarrow Set$ analogous?

Comment: Yes, this also has no right adjoint.